# Unable to Login to TFS via Jenkins plugin

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I'm trying to poll for changes in my TFS repository.

> Server URL: http://SERVER.com:8080/tfs/
>
> Project path: $/QA TFS Project
>
> Login name: DOMAIN\AaronH

When I run the job, I get this error:

> TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: http://SERVER.com:8080/tfs/
>   Team Foundation Server Url: http://SERVER.com:8080/tfs/.
>
> Possible reasons for failure include:
>
> > - The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
> > - The Team Foundation Server is offline.
> > - The password has expired or is incorrect.

I can log into the site through a browser with the same credentials.  I'm lost, I'm fairly new to Jenkins setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the URL including the project collection.  For example:

```
http://SERVER.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

Comment: I was hooked up to the wrong collection when I tried this.  Thank you.

Comment: it throws error If there is a space in project collection name, any idea to fix it?

Comment: @UsamaKhalil  It's a URL; escape your space with `%20`.  Eg: `Foo%20Bar` instead of "Foo Bar"